# Create Parent and Multiple Children in same view in ASP.NET MVC with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have been racking the web trying to find an easy solution (or at least a regular walk through) of what I would think would be a common activity, but I have been unable to find any. I have the following classes:

```
public class Attribute
{
    ...
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AttributeName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool UserCanChangeValue { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AttributeValue> Values { get; set; }
}

class AttributeValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AssociatedAttribute")]
    public int AssociatedAttributeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Attribute AssociatedAttribute { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool PromptChange { get; set; } = true;
    public bool ShowonInvoice { get; set; } = false;
}
```

Then in a standard controller:

```
...
// GET: AttributesController/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Description,Values")] Attribute newAttribute)
....
```

What I am confused on is how to create this where an attribute has to have 1 or more values that need to be created at the same time, and dynamically an attribute can have a variable number.  Ideally I would add rows to the form for each attribute value to create.

Some scaffolded details:

```
...
<form asp-action="Create">
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="AttributeName" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="AttributeName" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="AttributeName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="AttributeName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="UserCanChangeValue" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserCanChangeValue)
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th>Prompt Change</th>
                <th>Show on Invoice</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            INSERT DYNAMIC NEW VALUE FORM?
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Jon, I saw your AttributeValue does not contain any primary key, how is your DbContext like? Besides, your code works in asp.net core instead of asp.net. What is your target framework, `.NET 5` or `.NET 6`?

Comment: yikes!  I forgot that - it's there for sure

Comment: Hi @Jon, so any update for my following answer? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you set `PromptChange` and `ShowonInvoice` default value, if you make `checkbox/radio` input unchecked, they will pass the default value(`PromptChange= true` and `ShowonInvoice=false`) to backend. But actually, I prefer do not set default value which can control true/false by checked or unchecked. Not sure which way is what you want, just modify by yourself.

Then your class `AttributeValue` need public access modifier.

Here is a simple working demo you could follow:

Model:

```
namespace MvcProj5_0.Models
{
    public class Attribute
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string AttributeName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool UserCanChangeValue { get; set; }
        public ICollection<AttributeValue> Values { get; set; }
    }

    public class AttributeValue
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }     //add a primary key
        [ForeignKey("AssociatedAttribute")]
        public int AssociatedAttributeId { get; set; }
        public virtual Attribute AssociatedAttribute { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public bool PromptChange { get; set; } 
        public bool ShowonInvoice { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

View(Create.cshtml):

```
@model MvcProj5_0.Models.Attribute    
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="AttributeName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="AttributeName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="AttributeName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="AttributeName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="UserCanChangeValue" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserCanChangeValue)
        </label>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="AddRow()">Add row</button>    //add button
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Value</th>
                    <th>Prompt Change</th>
                    <th>Show on Invoice</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="AttributeValueList" data-count="0">         //add id  and data-count
                INSERT DYNAMIC NEW VALUE FORM?
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

JS in Create.cshtml:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script>
        function AddRow()
        {
            var countVal = parseInt($('#AttributeValueList').attr('data-count'));    
            var html = '';
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" name="Values[' + countVal + '].Value" class="form-control"/></td>';
            html += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="Values[' + countVal + '].PromptChange" value="true"/></td>';
            html += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="Values[' + countVal + '].ShowonInvoice" value="true"/></td>';
            html += '</tr>';
 
            $('#AttributeValueList').append(html);    
            countVal += 1;
            $('#AttributeValueList').attr('data-count', countVal);
        }
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(
     [Bind("Id,AttributeName,Description,UserCanChangeValue,Values")] MvcProj5_0.Models.Attribute attribute)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(attribute);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(attribute);
}
```